# Does A* always provide shortest path?

Tags: java, algorithm, a-star

I am trying to understand how A*, Uniform cost and greedy search algorithms work. I know that the way in which nodes are explored changes in all 3 algorithms (greedy will explore based on  heuristic value, A* based on heuristic plus distance, uniform based on distance).

I want to know if for a given source and destination should all 3 algorithms provide the shortest path (with just a different number of cities explored?) or can they provide a different path.

I am mostly confused due to the implementation part of - if you store nodes in queue then when you are about to explore the destination node you will have the shortest path for it but if you have queue of paths (and this queue is now sorted based on heuristic + distance) then you might not always get the shortest path.

Answer (score 6):

Not necessarily, it depends on your heuristic. See [this section in Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A*_search_algorithm#Admissibility_and_optimality) that explains it in detail.

To summarize, A* gives an optimal solution if the heuristic is *admissable* (meaning it never overestimates the cost).

Comment: Even if heuristic is non-admissable the A* algorithm will only stop when it is about to explore the destination node (it might explore many unnecessary paths due to non-admissable heuristics) and in that case it must have first explored all the paths reaching to that node so it will always find the shortest path isn't it?

Comment: @harrythomas No, as an extreme example consider a square grid with one end in the topleft corner, the other in the bottomright corner. I can make a heuristic that makes the algorithm follow a border first, which would result in a suboptimal solution.

Comment: Yes, but in that case when you explore the other edge you will find the shortest distance and you will update it right? or in A* star you don't update the shortest distance ?? Think about the way in which uniform cost search finds the shortest path (by updating the current shortest value with new value found)

Comment: @harrythomas In A* you terminate the algorithm when you find the target. You will never 'explore the other edge'.

Comment: So in A* you terminate the algorithm whenever you are about to put the destination in the queue for the first time unlike in uniform cost where you terminate search when you take out the node from queue to explore. am I correct?

Comment: @harrythomas There should be no difference between those two, as the admissibility requirement guarantees that if you put the destination in the queue, it should be the next element to be selected.

Answer (score 1):

In fact the heuristic should be admissible otherwise A* will find a suboptimal solution. I think the queue should not be ordinated by the distance of the next node but using the heuristic that will put as next node the most promising one. 
Think it as: the next node may be the most distant from the current one but at the same time it can be the nearest one to the destination.